# Self Sign Certificate and domain

Tags: c#, ssl

I created a self sign certificate using the following steps:

1. Create a Root certificate authority

> makecert -pe -n "CN=RootCertificate" -ss root -sr LocalMachine -sky signature -r "RootCertificate.cer"

2. Create an SSL certificate

> makecert -pe -n "CN=SSLCertificate" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -in "RootCertificate" -is root -ir LocalMachine -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 SSLCertificate.cer

3. Confirm RootCertifcate under Trusted Root Certificate, confirm SSLCertificate sits under Personal Certificates.
4. I exported SSLCertificate into SSLCertificate.pfx file using MMC GUI.
5. I import SSLCertificate.pfx into a server computer.
6. I bind this certificate to port 998 using the command:

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:998 certhash=‎764f3bef8cf4d72c5cd077da5b0efbec1b3830a5 appid={3fc1e120-6d8d-477e-ad09-67d749e65d83}

I have an application that hosts its own HTTP Listner on port 998.  I verified it works because I can browse to `https://server_ip:998`

My question is:  This server is currently on its own, what if it is part of the domain, would my step 1 - 6 be enough? In my opinion i think it should be but then again I'm not very familiar with the network side  and there is no domain for me to test this out.

I am not using IIS to host but rather it is a C# form application that hosts this HTTP Listener.

Comment: There is no relation between Windows domains and SSL certificates... So it will continue to work.

Comment: That's what I thought too because domain or DNS, if I posts to this HTTP listener, it will eventually arive at that port in which th encryption process will be taking place.  If you post your comment as asnwer, I'll accept it.

Comment: For testint purposes you can define pseudo domain - edit your `etc/hosts` file and define temp domain there. E.g. `mydomain.net    <ip>`. It will work only for your browser/PC but it is enough.